# Loading error when using jquery load funciton and mobile accordions

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, load, accordion

I'm currently using a very simple script to load an exterior php page into an html page (reason for the transfer is that the final html page will be embedded in an app). The exterior php page contains a layout for making jquery accordion setup. 1/5 times when i load the page (doesn't matter if its on a desktop, mobile browser, or the actual app) it will do one of three things, either load the page and not show no content (an inspection shows the code from the php page is there), load the page multiple times within itself (so there will be an accordion within an accordion within an accordion) or have the loading animation get stuck and keep spinning and not go away after the page is completely functional. Any ideas? here is the code in the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/themes/BCHS.min.css" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>BCHS Today</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.title {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.added_by {
    color:#999;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:9px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div id="container">

</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#container").load('http://bchs.wizuma.com/index.php', '', function     (response, status, xhr) {
                setTimeout("location.reload(true);", "5000");
                if (status == 'error') {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                }
            });
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

A very simple script, the link to the actual page is [here](http://bchs.wizuma.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a race condition. Try putting your code in a `$(document).ready()` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").load('http://bchs.wizuma.com/index.php', '', function(response, status, xhr) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload(true);
        }, 5000);
        if (status == 'error') {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        }
    });
});
```